# Circuit only works while touching the ground

Tags: voltage, pcb-design, ac, esp8266, pcb-antenna

so I am doing a small ESP8266 relay module. The relay is used as a SPDT switch so you can turn on the light with a normal switch on the wall but the module can shut them off after no motion is detected and vice versa. With this approach I need to know whether the light are already on or off so I don't turn on light that are already off.
To do this efficiently I used the flowing circuit:
[image]

The PCB is 4 layer stackup (top - GND - 3.3V - bottom). As an antenna I made a small 5-turn wire loop around the common pin on the relay contacts on the second layer (GND). I don't have a ground pour under the relay and AC supply. After I assembled the PCB I noticed some weird behaviour, but removing the LED and replacing it with a 1k resisitor and adding a 47uF electrolytic capacitor to the existing one I can get it to work but only if I physically touch the ground with my finger, if I don't it either doesn't change state or just pulses (50 Hz). I can't really scope the circuit  because when I connect the scope ground it works normally. This seems to be some grounding issue but I can't figure out how to fix this so if annyone has some input on it I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

The signal you collect with "ant" comes from AC wires through the capacitance between AC wires and "ant". To get some input current the GND should be at least capacitively connected to the earth of the mains AC system. That's seemingly already said by others one minute earlier.

Making the circuit slower by increasing capacitance C7 can make it deaf for phones, wifi, radio stations nearby and other unwanted higher frequency signals. I would place a RC lowpass filter to the input to have full control. The circuit can even be an oscillator due capacitive feedback from output to "ant" or due coupling via power supply if it has not narrow enough frequency range.

Multistage high gain amplifiers often have RC lowpass filters in the line which feeds +supply voltage to the preamp to prevent the feedback through common power rail. At least a short wire decoupling capacitor should be connected between +Vcc and GND as near the transistors as possible.